# Windows XP environment that is reproducable

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-server, cloning, clone

I want to set up a Windows XP environment that can be copied directly with the following properties:

1. Same programs/settings installed on all of the instances
2. Only things differing are necessary things (like network settings; IP and MAC addresses)

I'd like to run multiple instances of the same set-up on VMware with minimal effort in re-building the "master" image and starting a new instance.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You'd get better answers if you stated which VMWare product you're using. There's probably a way of doing it by copying the harddisk files, re-importing configs and having VMWare realize what you've done and offer to change the MAC address for you.

Comment: I'm using VMware Server.

Answer (score 6):

What Mikael said but I would sysprep the image so you get a unique SID if you are involved with a domain.

Then it will be real easy to just copy the image, deal with the networking ids, then run though just a few steps depending on how you sysprep the image.

Comment: +1 for recommending Sysprep. I always use Sysprep for any type of imaging where I'm creating a master image.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a fresh Windows XP virtual machine, then copy the machine directory (containing the files ending in **.vmx**, **.vmdk**, and so on).
They are stored in **~/.vmware** by default in Linux, unfortunately I have no idea where they are in Windows.

After that you may change the MAC address(es) by editing the **.vmx** file according to [this reference](http://sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-network-advanced.html).
The IP address however is of course defined in the operating system, but you could solve this by using DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

I do almost exactly this.

I have a "reference" XP image that has current patches, basic apps, etc.  When I need a new image, I just copy the entire directory to a new name.  Then when I open the copy in VMware Workstation, it asks me if I copied it or moved it; when I tell it the image was copied, VMware automatically fixes the MAC address.

The only problem is that one tends to go VM-happy when it is this easy to make copies -- I have something like nine or ten VMs on one laptop, and keeping them all patched is major work in itself sometimes.